# JSF Starting Page Redirect via f:event listener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss

In my application after the user has logged in, he is redirected to a specific page according to his role.
Since the upgrade from Primefaces 6.0 to Primefaces 8.0 the redirect implemented via f:event listener does not work any more. With 8.0 I get the following exception:

```
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

JBWEB000071: root cause 
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:420)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:602)
    eu.companyXY.qkb.br.web.session.BrUserSession.redirect(BrUserSession.java:86)
    eu.companyXY.qkb.br.web.session.BrUserSession$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.redirect(BrUserSession$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    eu.companyXY.qkb.br.web.target.**BrTargetBean.doRedirect**(BrTargetBean.java:98)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2485)
    javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2166)
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2111)
```

The method **doRedirect** is called in index.xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{targetSelect.doRedirect}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

and finally here is the method BrTargetBean.doRedirect:

```
public void doRedirect(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/main/br/datacorrections.xhtml");
}
```

With Primefaces 6.0 this code worked without any problem.
Do you have any idea about what's going wrong here ?

Also if you know another way of redirecting to a specific page after login please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You can redirect in the login method when it finishes. No need for eventlisteners at all

Comment: And actually there is nothing PF related in the stacktrace and PF does not control f:event so you must have done more than upgrade PrimeFaces.

Comment: @Melloware: technically speaking it's possible that something else has physically written to the response body before the preRenderView event was fired and that remains invisible in the stack trace. The OP should put a debug breakpoint on getResponseWriter() to figure out who/what did that.

Comment: Thanks BalusC: You are right s.th. has already written to the response, since the following prints "true":     ResponseFacade res = (ResponseFacade) ec.getResponse()     
System.out.println("response.isCommitted="+res.isCommitted()); However I do not have a clue where or why this happens ? Do you have an idea what I could check ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: That is mentioned in the comment above: _"The OP should put a debug breakpoint on getResponseWriter() to figure out who/what did that."_